# Delete the first sheet of multiple excel sheet and consolidate remaining with R

Tags: r

I have multiple excel files having different number of sheets in each file. The 1st sheet of each files is named summary. I want to get rid of the summary sheet of each file and consolidate the other sheets in a data frame.

I have files names 1.xlsx, 2.xlsx .... 343.xlsx. Each excel file contains multiple sheets. For example, 1.xlsx contains sheets names summary, Delhi, Noida 
2.xlsx contains sheets names summary, Mumbai, Pune, Goa, Hyderabad and so on.

I need to delete summary sheet of all 343 files and merge all other sheets of each file in a single data frame

The number of rows and columns are not same

Example:
Sheet x contains the following data:

[image: Content of sheetx]

Sheet y contains the following data:

[image: Content of sheetx]

Desired output:

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Can you please edit your code into your post? It is much easier for us to help you if we can copy + paste your code into R, as opposed to manually typing out a screenshot (it's faster and less likely to lead to errors). In addition, some data would be useful so that we have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all tabs except `Summary` in each excel file have same column names -

```r
library(readxl)   

f_in <- list.files("directory_path_of_your_excel_files/")

read_all_tabs <- function(f_name) {
  tabs <- excel_sheets(f_name)
  tabs <- tabs[-1]
  tab_data <- lapply(tabs, function(x) read_excel(f_name, sheet = x))
  names(tab_data) <- tabs
  tab_data
}

df <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(f_in, function(x) Reduce(rbind, read_all_tabs(x))))
```

**Edit:** Since all sheets have different number of rows/ columns and your requirement is to column bind these data I think `cbind.na` would be handy.

```
library(qpcR)
df <- Reduce(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(f_in, function(x) Reduce(qpcR:::cbind.na, read_all_tabs(x))))
```

Comment: The number of columns are not same.

Comment: How is the layout? I think you should share the sample data & column layout from each sheet by updating your original post?

Comment: its showing this error  Error: Unknown file extension: r

Comment: Can you paste the code that generated this error? What exactly were you trying to perform when you got the error? You may need to provide more details so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: f_in <- list.files("my path/")

read_all_tabs <- function(f_name) {
  tabs <- excel_sheets(f_name)
  tabs <- tabs[-1]
  tab_data <- lapply(tabs, function(x) read_excel(f_name, sheet = x))
  names(tab_data) <- tabs
  tab_data
}

library(qpcR)
install.packages("qpcR")
df <- Reduce(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(f_in, function(x) Reduce(qpcR:::cbind.na, read_all_tabs(x))))

Comment: Which line of code generated this error? You can find this by running each line one by one (BTW I had tested my code and it worked fine). At first glance I found that you need to first install a package before using it in `library(qpcR)`. Also 1) not sure if you have included `library(readxl)` at the beginning and 2) `my path/` should be a complete path not relative with `/`.

Comment: i am aware of all these points. the last line where i created a data frame generated this error

Comment: Is the folder `my path/` having your code as well? If yes then you may need to consider placing it outside because it seems `read_excel()` is trying to read that file as well.

Comment: done. but its showing a new error, Error in matrix(...) : non-numeric matrix extent

Comment: i have done the following steps successfully. 1) i deleted the summary sheet of each file 2) i have extracted all sheets of a file as a separate sheet so that each excel files contain only 1 sheet. but i dont know how to column bind a list.. is there anything similar to rbindlist??

Comment: Without actual reproducible example it's almost impossible to identify the root cause. To debug this issue I would have executed `l <-
 lapply("your_excel_file_full_path/excel_file.xlsx", function(x) Reduce(qpcR:::cbind.na, read_all_tabs(x)))` and then `class(l)` to see if it's still a list and so on... Seems like it has to do something with the data in your excel file